# Using jQuery, access a previously appended element

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to access elements with jQuery that have already been appended earlier. I understand that dynamically added elements can't be seen using 'normal' commands - and I've seen a number of other questions involving .link() and .on() - but I'm not sure how to apply those answers in this case. Apologies for the possible duplication, but I'm new to jQuery.

Here's a basic example - where I add a row and a cell to a table (this would normally be in a loop) - and put an image in the cell. Then at a later point, I want to access the src of this image and change it:

```
addTableRows = function(){
    $("#tableBody")
        .append($("<tr class='tableRow>")
            .append($("<td valign='top' align='center'>")                               
                .append($("<img src='expand-icon.gif'>")
                    .attr('id','expand-icon')
                    .click(function(){
                         iconClicked();
                    }))));

iconClicked = function(){
    var test = $("#expand-icon").attr("src");
    alert(test);
}
```

At the moment, `test` comes back as "undefined". How can I access the `expand-icon` image?

---

**EDIT:**

(Adding more detail to include loop and unique ids for table cells)

```
addTableRows = function(response){
    var members = response['member'];
    $.each(members, function (idx, data) {
        var currentID = data['identifier'];
        $("#tableBody")
            .append($("<tr class='tableRow'>")
                .append($("<td valign='top' align='center'>")                               
                    .append($("<img src='expand-icon.gif'>")
                        .attr('id','expand-icon' + currentID)
                        .click(function(){
                             iconClicked(currentID);
                        })
                    )
                )
        );
    });
}

iconClicked = function(currentID){
    var test = $("#expand-icon" + currentID).attr("src");
    alert(test);
}
```

Comment: just a note, you don't need multiple `append`. One with complete row is sufficient.

Comment: You can use `$(this)` inside click callback, to access current element, img in your case.

Comment: @SachinG: The "real" code is much longer, I assumed one giant append line would be poor coding. But do the multiple appends just cause problems?  
@jcubic Could you explain where you would add `$(this)`? Do you mean something like `$(this).click(function)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK. What you have is syntax errors:

```
.append($("<tr class='tableRow>")
```

The row above lacks a `'` after `tableRow`.
You also lacked a closing `};` for `addTableRows = function() {`, right before the `iconClicked = function...` line.

Next time, tools like TidyUp and JSHint (see the buttons at JSFiddle) may help making your code clearer, making it easier to spot errors like these.

Here's a fixed version:

```
addTableRows = function () {
    $("#tableBody").append(
           $("<tr class='tableRow'>").append( // added ' here
               $("<td valign='top' align='center'>").append(
                    $("<img src='expand-icon.gif'>").attr('id', 'expand-icon').click(function () { iconClicked(); })
               )
           )
    );
}; // added this here

iconClicked = function () {
    var test = $("#expand-icon").attr("src");
    alert(test);
};
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/Jy43L/).

## Edit:

Besides the syntax corrections pointed above, if you want to handle the addition and click of **multiple** rows, you have some alternatives:

- **[Demo fiddle for alternative one.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/Jy43L/2/)**
- **[Demo fiddle for alternative two.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/Jy43L/3/)**

### Alternative one:

To keep you code change to a minimum, you can change only `iconClicked()` to get the clicket image through `event.target`:

```
iconClicked = function(){
    var test = $(event.target).attr("src");
    alert(test);
}
```

This will handle the eventual multiple IDs, but, nevertheless, you should avoid them.

### Alternative two (best option):

My personal favorite, ditch `iconClicked()` and just use `on()` to handle the click events:

```
addTableRows = function(imageId, imageSrc){
    $("#tableBody").append(
        $("<tr>").addClass('tableRow').append(
            $("<td>").attr('valign','top').attr('align','center').append(
                $("<img>").attr('id', imageId).attr('src',imageSrc)
            )
        )
    );
};
$('#tableBody').on('click', '.tableRow img', function(){
    var test = $(this).attr("src");
    alert(test);
});

addTableRows('expand-icon1', 'http://his-booking.com/images/flag_br.gif');
addTableRows('expand-icon2', 'http://bc.id.au/images/fr_flag.gif');
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that if `addTableRows` is called multiple times, the `iconClicked` function will not behave as expected as the id's will not be unique.

Comment: @dc5 Yes, you are correct. Made sure I addressed this in my edit.

Comment: @acdcjunior thank you! Sorry for the initial errors, I added that quickly to get the idea across. I'll remember not to use simplified code in future! I've edited the question to include the loop I'm using, and also the unique ids for the table cells. Does that effect your answer? Apologies if so.

Comment: I believe it doesn't. The principles remain. An example fiddle using your updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/Jy43L/4/ (notice I changed the `iconClicked()` a bit to show the ID so you can see their value changes according to the flag clicked).

Comment: How did it go? Although [the fiddle I posted in the comment above](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/Jy43L/6/) makes your code work with the smallest effort possible, I'd prefer [**this solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/Jy43L/6/).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this way..

you can write:`

```
$(".tableRowExpand").click(function(){

var test = $(this).find('#expand-icon').attr("src");
alert(test);

});
```

add tableRowExpand to your ing class attribute
But be aware that you have multiple expand-icon ids in your document. ids should be unique.. use classes instead.

Okay, this is it complete:

```
function addTableRows()
{   
    $("#tableBody").append("<tr class='tableRow'><td valign='top' align='center'><img src='expand-icon.gif' class='tableRowExpand'></td></tr>");
}

$(".tableRowExpand").click(function(){

var test = $(this).attr("src");
alert(test);
var tablerow = $(this).parent().parent();
var tablecell = $(this).parent();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do actually use unique ids (see the edited question) - but they are defined dynamically in the loop, e.g. `'expand-icon' + currentID`. Could your approach of `$(".tableRowExpand").click` be modified to suit this? I'm not sure it can be done when it does not know what `currentID` is?

Answer (score 0):

First, `id` attributes need to be unique across a page. Try changing that to a class instead.

Second, you can change your handler to this:

```
.click(iconClicked);
```

If you have a function, you don't need to wrap that in an anonymous function.

Third, you can use `this` in an event handler to reference the element that was clicked:

```
iconClicked = function(){
    var test = $(this).attr("src");
    alert(test);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if I used your `$(this)` approach above, would unique ids/classes not be required? Should it just know what element has been clicked on?  I tried modifying iconClicked like above - but I still get `undefined` in the alert.